# PHP: Help restructuring JSON Array

Tags: php, json

I have this simple json object:

```
$colours = '{"num":20,"status":"ok","colour0":"red","colour1":"green","colour2":"blue"}';
```

How can I turn into this with PHP:

```
$colours = '[{"colour":"red"},{"colour":"green"},{"colour":"blue"}]';
```

Do I need to json_decode() it first ?

I tried this with no luck:

```
$jsonArr = json_decode($similarsites, true);
$c1 = parse_url($jsonArr['c1']);

$ii = 0;
$resulti = array('color' => array());

while (isset($jsonArr['c' . $ii])) {
        $c = $jsonArr['c' . $ii];

        $resulti['color'][$ii] = $c;
        $ii++ ;
    }

print json_encode($resulti['color']);
```

But this gives me the list of all colours not as key/value

Comment: You can't have the same key multiple times in an object.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry please check my edit

Comment: You would be better off just returning an array of colours, e.g. `{"red","green","blue"}`

Comment: @ClydeM your edit is irrelevant to Barmar's response

Comment: why you use `$jsonArr['c' . $ii]` instead of `$jsonArr['colour' . $ii]`?

Comment: @Ryan No, his edit solves the problem. Now he has an array of objects, not a single object.

Comment: `"num":20` should be `"num":"20"`. you cannot miss the quotes

Comment: My edit of [{"colour":"red"},{"colour":"green"},{"colour":"blue"}], is a perfectly Valid JSON: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @Barmar I see now, it updated then reverted for me so I saw his original post. It's now showing correctly.

Comment: @user2936213 Its given from an API

Comment: where have you defined `$datax`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ii = 0;
$resultArr = array();
while (isset($jsonArr['colour' . $ii])) {
    $resultArr[] = array('colour' => $jsonArr['colour' . $ii]);
    $ii++;
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/7n4ZFm)

Comment: sir this line gives me an error: $resultArr[] = array('colour' => $jsonArr['colour' + $ii]));

Comment: Sorry, I had an extra parenthesis

Comment: Thank you. After if I use: print json_encode($resultArr); Ι just get two brackets: [] - or an empty json object

Comment: It seems that isset($jsonArr['colour' + $ii]) is false because right after that I am echo "empty"; with no result

Comment: Fixed it. `+` should be `.` (too much switching between PHP and JS). And `i++` should be `$ii++`.

Comment: haha. Yap just mentioned thank you. Now another problem exists. All values returned are null.

Comment: It seems that $jsonArr['colour' + $ii] gives null

Comment: Within the loop I tried var_dump($jsonArr['colour' + $ii]); which gives me all null values

Comment: It should be `.` not `+`.